# What geometry or topology best embodies the nonlocality of quantum entanglement?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

I am a Princeton physics major.

What geometry or topology best embodies the nonlocality of quantum entanglement?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement: "Each particle cannot be described independently of the state of the other(s), ***even when the particles are separated by a large distance***."

So it is that even when the particles are separated by a great distance, they interact as if they yet share the same common locality.

What geometry or topology best embodies the physical properties of quantum nonlocality and entanglement?

Is there a geometry or topology which describes a sphere whence all the points on the surface of the sphere can yet be seen to inhabit the same locality?

Thanks!

Comment: This will probably have to be the indiscrete topology, where every point is infinitely near all other points. The reason is that, depending on the experimental set-up, a particle at any point could "interact as if they yet share a common locality" with a particle at any other point.  Another way to say the same thing: Topology isn't going to help make quantum non-locality look local.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thank you!  where are the best places to learn ore about "Indiscrete Topology?"

Comment: There's essentially nothing to learn about the indiscrete topology (also called the trivial topology). It's the topology where the only open sets are the empty set and the whole space.